# Understanding Java behaviour in recursive factorial

Tags: java, recursion, decrement

I created two recursive methods to calculate factorial as follows:

```
private int fact1(int n) {
    if (n == 0 || n == 1)
        return 1;
    return n * fact1(--n);

}

private int fact2(int n) {
    if (n == 0 || n == 1)
        return 1;
    return fact2(--n) * n;
}
```

When I call `fact1(4)` it returns `24`. When I call `fact2(4)` it returns `6` (**EDIT**: is not returning `18` but `6`). I know the second method is making 3 * 2 * 1, but I don't understand why not 4 * 3 * 2 * 1.

The same happens if I change the return to

```
//fact3(4) returns 60.
return (n + 1) * fact3(--n); // wrong
//fact4(4) returns 24
return fact4(--n) * (n + 1); // works
```

Why is the method exhibiting this behavior??

The question is about the different behaviour. I know `n * fact(n-1)` is the better way to solve it.

Can someone help me to understand the evaluation of this expression? Thanks!

Comment: It's strange how nobody pointed out yet that `fact2(4)` is actually `6`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It all comes down to the difference between these expressions:

```
return n * f(--n);

return f(--n) * n;
```

When `n = 4`, these expressions are evaluated like this:

```
return 4 * f(3);

return f(3) * 3;
```

Because the moment `--n` is evaluated, the value of `n` is decreased by 1.
This is how the prefix `--` operator works.

It might help to recursively evaluate the entire expressions by hand. The first one:

```
// first
return 4 * f(3);
return 4 * 3 * f(2);
return 4 * 3 * 2 * f(1);
return 4 * 3 * 2 * 1;

// second
return f(3) * 3;
return f(2) * 2 * 3;
return f(1) * 1 * 2 * 3;
return 1 * 1 * 2 * 3;
```

On a related note, guess how this will be evaluated:

```
return f(n--) * n;
```

It will be:

```
return f(4) * 3;
```

Because here the postfix `--` operator is used: the -1 decrement will be applied after the evaluation of `n` in `f(...)`.

Comment: In your 2nd line, when `f(3)` is evaluated what is the behaviour? Why the 2nd call returns `f(2) * 3`?

Comment: If you mean `fact2(3)`, the same logic applies as in my 2nd line but with `n = 3`, so that becomes `f(2) * 2`

Comment: Are you saying the expression is (f(2) * 2) * 3? It returns 6. But running the code here is returning 18.

Comment: Actually, yes, your must be running something else to get 18, because your posted methods return 24 and 6, respectively

Comment: Ok, I will check. Thanks for the answer